# Paint with shadow layer - how to change alpha

Tags: android, user-interface

I try to change transparency of my paint which has set shadow layer. When I used `paint.setAlpha(x)`, my paint transparency was changed but shadow layer didn't. As I want to use it during `onDraw` animation i rather **dont want to set new shadow layer** in every frame.

Please see my implementation:

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setShadowLayer(shadowRadius, shadowDx, shadowDy, shadowColor);
```

And then in `onDraw()`:

```
paint.setAlpha((int)(255 * deltaT / ANIMATION_TIME));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer. But it can be helpful to others.

According to the documentation of `setShadowLayer`:

> The alpha of the shadow will be the paint's alpha if the shadow color
> is opaque, or the alpha from the shadow color if not.

So, if you want the `Paint`'s `alpha` property to affect the shadow layer, you must use an opaque color (full alpha channel e.g. #FF444444).